# What does $\Phi\vert_S$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, abelian-groups, free-groups

In Abstract Algebra (Dummit and Foote) Exercise 11 in Section 6.3 (A Word on Free Groups) it says:

> ... Prove that $A(S)$ has the following universal property: if $G$ is any abelian group and $\varphi:S\rightarrow G$ is any set map, then there is a unique homomorphism $\Phi:A(S)\rightarrow G$ such that $\Phi\vert_S=\varphi$. ...

The notation is not introduced in the book and I wouldn't like to take any wrong assumption.

Comment: Restriction of $\Phi$ to $S$

Comment: $\Phi\mid_S=\phi$ is defined by the equation $\Phi(x)=\phi(x)$ for all $x\in S$, but not necessarily for all $x$ in $A(S)$.

Comment: It's set theory notation, the restriction of a function to a subset, in this case the retriction of the function $\Phi$ to the subset $S$.

Comment: The notation is defined on page $3$ of Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 1):

One way of saying it is, if we consider the inclusion $i:S\hookrightarrow A(S)$, then $\Phi|_S=\Phi\circ i$.